# make Blender displays vertex color of unselected faces, WITHOUT Blender's white-mix foggy mask

Tags: customization, vertex-colors

The below image shows the vertex color of an object.
[image]

The vertex color of left & right parts are exactly symmatric (R,G,B,Black,White).

However, if I select only right faces, the left faces will be fade (show below).

When I paint, the white-mix-looking of unselected faces (half left) makes me confuse.
How to remove the white foggy that the blender paint over unselected face?
I still want the white outline to show.

[image]

The setting should be somewhere in **Preferences>Themes>3D Viewport**, but I can't find it.

It is probably in overlay setting (in the below image), but I can find a solution without turn wireframe off all together.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Couldn't find anything under Preference-->Themes either. And Viewport Overlays 'Fade Inactive Geometry' only works on object level.

Comment: You can deactivate ALL viewport overlays (by clicking show overlays icon) to get rid of the white overlay. But there doesn't seem to be separate options for only deactivating the overlay of non-active geometry.