# How can I use the "Fill" in texture paint on only a single face instead of the entire uv map?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

Kinda like what I did with the red in the image, but more precise with the drawing. Also I'm pretty new to Blender so don't expect me to know everything yet[image: Red]

Comment: Might be easier to isolate the face in the 3D viewport in edit mode and paint directly there

Comment: If all your "painting" is per face you can use vertex paint mode and paint per face (instead of vertex). https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/80205/2214

Answer (score 3):

1. select your object
2. choose texture paint from the menu
3. tab -> edit mode
4. choose "face select mode"

[image]

5. select the faces you want to paint on
6. tab -> texture paint mode
7. click this button: paint mask

[image]

8. paint what you want -> now you just paint on that faces you selected
9. you can select the faces in the texture paint view too...just tap on select and choose your favorite selection mode

[image]

you can check a tutorial video here:

https://youtu.be/TYq49SLlot8.  (just be a little bit patient, my internet is not fast)