# How to assign different faces of the same object different materials?

Tags: materials, node-editor, faces, vertex-groups

I have subdivided a plane into 50 x 50 faces, 
then I random selected some of those faces and saved them as a group, 
I hid them with <kbd>h</kbd> and random selected among the other faces and made them another group.

I repeated this a couple of time, so that I had one objected which contained several groups of faces.

From this point on, I tried to select one group and assign to them one material and to another group another material and so on...basically to achieve a floor of tiles with different kind of tiles.

But, it did not work.

Comment: What didn't work?

Comment: when I selected the vertex group and assigned a material only to the selected faces, not the faces changed but the whole object

Comment: How many materials there are available? Were you *assigning* faces to the vertex group? Keep in mind that faces won't be assigned if you just selected them with vertex group choosed in the list. Please show some screenshots of how were you assigning and what was the result.

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77885/935) can be adjusted to assign random materials to faces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Click "+" to add a new material slot
2. Set the material
3. Select the desired face(s) and make sure the added slot is selected
4. Click "Assign" button

You should see it in the viewport (solid) now
[image]