# Apply a different material to every face

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

I just wanted to know if it was possible to apply a different material to every face. So if a model has 200 faces there is 200 materials. I could do this the manual way but I would rather not.

Thanks for the help

Comment: So you have 200 different materials and you want to assign them? Random?

Comment: Yeah, that’s fine as long as each face has its own material

Comment: It should be possible, but if not manually, you'll need a python script to automate this task.But you added the "texturing" tag, so if you just wish to set a different _texture_ to each face, you could do this with a "simple" UVmap.

Comment: Any idea how I can achieve that? Link would help as well

Comment: see my updated comment above, but to learn scripting, start here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/scripting/index.html, then see also https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Materials/Multiple_Materials

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77885/935) creates a material for every face.