# How to pass 2nd input through a muted node?

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes

I'm improving the node setup from here: [Performance ?, which is better, taking a 4k image and splitting it up, or using material with full 4k image and changing the texture coords?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/229557/60486)

And I thought it would be useful to easily change the default behavior of numbering the tiles in left-to-right, bottom-to-top fashion, to an order more intuitive in 2D world: left-to-right, top-to-bottom, as well as to allow right-to-left too.

My idea to make it as simple as possible is to use Math > Subtract node to flip the value and then mute it, advising that the ordering can be reversed by unmuting the node:

[image]

However, the GUI clearly shows it is the static *columns* value that is passed when the node is muted, while **I want this**:

[image]

I'm aware I could work around this problem by e.g. flipping the inputs, so the input I want to pass through (coming from *Modulo*) is first, and then add another node: *Math > absolute* to make the math correct. But ideally this could be done without reducing the readability of the node setup...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the node and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> then make sure to flip the 1st and 2nd inputs:

[image]

Now the first value passed through is actually the 2nd value in the Math node inside the group:

[image]

This doesn't mess with the node layout, but it may confuse the reader on what the node group actually does, and I don't know how it affects performance.