# Non-procedural tiles in blender

Tags: texturing, materials

Good day everyone!
I've got 5 textures of a porcelain stoneware (tiles). Their size is quite big (60 cm x 119 cm), so it's not the usual small tiles. I tried experimenting with brick texture but I can't make it the right size, because the texture settings do not allow the control over the exact size of a brick, and I also got problems with applying the material to it. I also tried wooden floor addon, but again ran into problems applying the materials. Thought about making the tile texture of those 5 in photoshop, but it would be too repeated, and I want it to be more randomized. Of course I could make each tile individually and place them by hand, but it would not be efficient. Perhaps some gentlemen and ladies here could come up with an idea.
I want to place these 5 textures on and object as tiles and make them randomized, I'm making a bathroom. But can't understand how to make it good and efficient.
Thank you!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you rephrase your post so your question is a little more clear ? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi. What's your question? How to make them seemless or how to map them onto an object? What's your goal?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, if you want to make non repeatable tiles, you could use a porcelain texture and put your islands independently over the image in the UV Editor, scale them, rotate, etc

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake, completely forgot to ask a question. c:
I want to place these 5 textures on and object as tiles and make them randomized, I'm making a bathroom. But can't understand how to make it good and efficient. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Have a look into: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15076/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-have-a-material-randomize-the-image-textures-it-uses (related or dupe)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the easiest way to have a material randomize the Image textures it uses?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15076/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-have-a-material-randomize-the-image-textures-it-uses)

Comment: Thank you!
But it doesn't quite solves the problem. Because the tiles do not fit on some walls in one piece, so i need to cut them somehow. I've put an image in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this node tree setup:

[image]

I made just 3 planes with 3 different materials.

Randomly i choose one of them in the geometry nodes setup.

result:

[image]

and of course, with every different seed, you get another result:

[image]

UPDATE:

just found out...it is even easier with collection:

[image]

other seed:

[image]

UPDATE:

I copied my result 3 times, moved them and added a cube.

To the one i added a boolean modifier and i got this:

[image]

blend file: [image]

Comment: Thank you!
But the problem is that some tiles do not fit onto a wall as one piece and there's some small corners as well, so i need to cut them somehow. How do I make it work? I'll put an image to the post so it's easier to understand.

Comment: did you try the boolean modifier?

Comment: No, I did not.
So I make a plane using geometry nodes with those tiles, stick it onto the walls and use boolean on this plane?

Comment: i added my blend file so you can check it out

Comment: it doesn't care which object you take for the geometry nodes modifier because it will generate a new one from the grid.

Comment: Thank you!
Got it how to do this, last question is how can I control the gap between the tiles? To make it a little bit smaller.

Comment: Just change the sizex/sizey in the grid node