# How to make image textures map to generated masks to randomize placement on separate objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, objects, masking

I found some high quality floor textures, but they are a part of a Mulit Texture pack, so its multiple images of individual floorboards. I'm trying to create a node arrangement that assigns a solid color to each floorboard and uses the object info node to randomize the placement.

*Complete Node Arrangement*
[image]

*Complete Mask*
[image]

I'm also using greater than and less than nodes to adjust the amount of each color in the complete mask.

*Color-In Range Node*
[image]

I want to use this mask to drive the factor for a MixColor between the different Diffuse maps, assigning each to the corresponding colors from the mask. The arrangement I have now gets the mask generated correctly, and it has limited adjustment. When introducing the image textures, it appears to be working in the material preview, but the render in cycles just shows a flattened version of the mask for the flooring.

*Material Preview*
[image]
*Render Preview*
[image]

Is there something I'm missing/ a way to correct this to get it to work properly? For reference, I'm using Cycles and this is present in both 3.41 and 3.5. I haven't been able to find any other cases of people creating a node arrangement for Multi Texture floorboards, looking for some help/ advice for this!

Comment: how many textures do you have?

Comment: @lemon 16 right now, but even when i reduce the arrangement to only combine 2 textures, it comes out the same

Comment: Why not combine those textures into one, especially as they seem to have same dimensions, so you don't need to have a list of UV coordinates, just arrange the planks in some kind of a grid (16×1 or 8×2), and then randomize UV offsets [What is the easiest way to have a material randomize the Image textures it uses?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15076/60486) Doing it your way is probably very heavy on GPU with that many operations of sampling textures and mixing colors.